# Showing read only data in a label on a form (508 implications)

Tags: accessibility, html, labels, labeling

One of the definitions of a HTML label is:

> The HTML label element associates a piece of text to a control

What is the correct way to render HTML when the label itself is **NOT** "for" another **label**?

Example (to make it clear)

LabelA -> is for LabelB (which is read only text)

LabelB -> is for? (not really anything)

When 508 compliance checks run against things like this, LabelB is considered an "orphan" because it is not "for" anything. I could do a read only textbox but why even show that UI when a user cannot edit it?

EDIT:
Removing the misleading label tag and replacing it with a DIV, passes checks.

Comment: What is labelB actually being used for? Is it a piece of explanatory text for an earlier input, or something else entirely?

Comment: E.g. LabelA says "Account Number", LabelB -> shows the value which cannot be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A label that is “for” another label makes no sense, and a label that is “for” a field that accepts no input does not make much sense either. The obvious solution (to whatever is the problem here) is to not use labels like that.

[Section 508 rules](https://www.section508.gov/index.cfm?fuseAction=stdsdoc#Web) on web information and applications require that when a form is used, “the form shall allow people using assistive technology to access the information, field elements, and functionality required for completion and submission of the form, including all directions and cues”. So it does not say anything formal about label. Any “checks” are thus just advisory. But it looks obvious that *misleading* labeling, such as assigning labels to read-only fields, violate both accessibility and usability requirements.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the alternative? Literal Text?

Comment: If it’s an explanation of non-editable data, then yes, it needs no special markup (or there is no suitable markup).